# Как сделать чтобы div с абсолютным позиционированием внутри другого, не влиял на скролл страницы?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Есть div контейнер. Внутри него другой див с `position: absolute`, который больше самого контейнера. Это нужно, потому что расположение отсчитывается от краев именно контейнера. Контейнер допустим шириной 800 пикселей по центру страницы, а проблемный div 1000 пикселей. Нужно, чтобы скролл появлялся только когда окно становится меньше самого контейнера.

```
body{overflow-x: hidden;} - не решение, скролл всё же нужен.
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант добавить еще один оберточный див с `overflow-x: hidden`
т.е. структура должна быть [такая](http://jsfiddle.net/YE97M/)